# what jdbc jar to use with oracle 11g & jdk 1.6 and how to connect to the db itself

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm writing a database accessor in Java. The database is in Oracle 11g, of which I am absolutely not familiar, and I have JDK 1.6.

1. Will ojdbc4.jar do for my program? We're not allowed to connect to the Internet in the office and I can't download ojdbc6.jar, which I've read is more compatible with my setup.
2. What strings should I put in the Class.forName(String driver) and DriverManager.getConnection(String connectionURL)? I don't know the driver string and the connection URL since they (naturally) look very different from the ones for MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Oracle bundle the Jar with the Oracle client or server installation and can be found in `$ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar`.  I always use that one.
2. The Driver classname is `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` and the URL is `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE`.

Here's an example (taken from [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC)):

```
import java.sql.*;
class Conn {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
  {
   Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
     ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl", "scott", "tiger");
                        // @//machineName:port/SID,   userid,  password
   try {
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     try {
       ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select BANNER from SYS.V_$VERSION");
       try {
         while (rset.next())
           System.out.println (rset.getString(1));   // Print col 1
       } 
       finally {
          try { rset.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
       }
     } 
     finally {
       try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
     }
   } 
   finally {
     try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Class.forName is not needed. 2) Too many try/catch. It's enought to close connection and it will automatically close everything 3) I'm not sure, but in your case orcl is not a service, so the url should be jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:orcl

Comment: Thanks! Anyway, is the service token optional? Or can that be the name of the database I'm connecting to?

Comment: @matkiros Yes it is optional.

Comment: So where do I put the name of the database I'm connecting to?

Comment: UPDATE: The format for the argument to DriverManager.getConnection() above might cause an SQLException saying, "The Network Adapter could not establish the connection." To fix, try this syntax instead: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER:PORT_NUMBER/DATABASE_NAME` where the port number is optional.

Answer (score 6):

The offical JAR file in combination with JDK 1.6 is `ojdbc6.jar`. But `ojdbc4.jar` should work for most applications.

Typicall connection strings are:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:user/xxxx@server:port:SID
jdbc:oracle:thin:user/xxxx@//server:port/XE
jdbc:oracle:thin:user/xxxx@:SID
```