# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, tomcat7

I wrote a Java Servlet program but when I run it, it was showing the Exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

My code is

```
package skypark;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Date;

public class Registration extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static Connection prepareConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String dcn = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@JamesPJ-PC:1521:skypark";
        String usname = "system";
        String pass = "tiger";
        Class.forName(dcn);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, usname, pass);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        try {
            String phone1, dofb, date1, month, year, uname, fname, lname, address, city, state, country;
            String pin, email, password, gender, lang, qual, relegion, privacy, hobbies, fav;

            uname = req.getParameter("uname");
            fname = req.getParameter("fname");
            lname = req.getParameter("lname");
            date1 = req.getParameter("date");
            month = req.getParameter("month");
            year = req.getParameter("year");
            address = req.getParameter("address");
            city = req.getParameter("city");
            state = req.getParameter("state");
            country = req.getParameter("country");
            pin = req.getParameter("pin");
            email = req.getParameter("email");
            password = req.getParameter("password");
            gender = req.getParameter("gender");
            phone1 = req.getParameter("phone");

            lang = "";
            qual = "";
            relegion = "";
            privacy = "";
            hobbies = "";
            fav = "";

            dofb = date1 + "-" + month + "-" + year;
            int phone = Integer.parseInt(phone1);
            DateFormat formatter;
            java.util.Date dob;
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
            dob = formatter.parse(dofb);

            Connection con = prepareConnection();
            String Query = "Insert into regdetails values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(Query);

            ps.setString(1, uname);
            ps.setString(2, fname);
            ps.setString(3, lname);
            ps.setDate(4, (Date) dob);
            ps.setString(5, address);
            ps.setString(6, city);
            ps.setString(7, state);
            ps.setString(8, country);
            ps.setString(9, pin);
            ps.setString(10, lang);
            ps.setString(11, qual);
            ps.setString(12, relegion);
            ps.setString(13, privacy);
            ps.setString(14, hobbies);
            ps.setString(15, fav);
            ps.setString(16, gender);

            int c = ps.executeUpdate();

            String query = "insert into passmanager values(?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(query);

            ps1.setString(1, uname);
            ps1.setString(2, password);
            ps1.setString(3, email);
            ps1.setInt(4, phone);

            int i = ps1.executeUpdate();

            if (c == 1 || c == Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO && i == 1 || i == Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO) {
                out.println("<html><head><title>Login</title></head><body>");
                out.println("<center><h2>Skypark.com</h2>");
                out.println("<table border=0><tr>");
                out.println("<td>UserName/E-Mail</td>");
                out.println("<form action=login method=post");
                out.println("<td><input type=text name=uname></td>");
                out.println("</tr><tr><td>Password</td>");
                out.println("<td><input type=password name=pass></td></tr></table>");
                out.println("<input type=submit value=Login>");
                out.println("</form></body></html>");
            } else {
                out.println("<html><head><title>Error!</title></head><body>");
                out.println("<center><b>Given details are incorrect</b>");
                out.println(" Please try again</center></body></html>");
                RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("registration.html");
                rd.include(req, resp);
                return;
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            out.println("<html><head><title>Error!</title><body>");
            out.println("<b><i>Class not found " + cnfe + "</i></b>");
            out.println("</body></html>");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            out.println("<html><head><title>Error!</title><body>");
            out.println("<b><i>Unable to process try after some time Sql error</i></b>");
            out.println("</body></html>");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            out.println("<html><head><title>Error!</title><body>");
            out.println("<b><i>Unable to process Parseint exc " + e + "</i></b>");
            out.println("</body></html>");
        }

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

My class path is :

```
C: \Windows\ system32 > echo % classpath %
  E: \app\ JamesPJ\ product\ 11.2.0\ dbhome_1\ oui\ jlib\ classes12.jar;
E: \app\ JamesPJ\ product 11.2.0\ dbhome_1\ jlib\ orai18n.jar;
E: \app\ JamesPJ\ product\ 11.2.0\ dbhome_1\ jdbc\ lib\ ojdc6_g.jar;
E: \app\ JamesPJ\ product\ 11.2.0\ dbhome_1\ BIN;
C: \Program Files\ Java\ jdk1.7.0_09\ bin;
C: \Users\ JamesPJ\ Documents;
E: \app\ JamesPJ\ product\ 11.2.0\ dbhome_1\ jdbc\ lib;
E: \app\ JamesPJ\ product\ 11.2.0\ dbhome_1\ jlib;
E: \app\ JamesPJ\ product\ 11.2.0\ dbhome_1\ jdbc\ lib\ ojdbc6.jar;
E: \app\ JamesPJ\ product\ 11.2.0\ dbhome_1\ oc4j\ jdbc\ lib\ orai18n.jar;
E: \app\ JamesPJ\ product\ 11.2.0\ dbhome_1\ oc4j\ jdbc\ lib\ ocrs12.jar;
E: \app\ JamesPJ\ product\ 11.2.0\ dbhome_1\ owb\ wf\ lib\ ojdbc14.jar;
C: \Program Files\ Apache Software Foundation\ Tomcat 7.0\ lib\ servlet - api.jar
```

When I give the

```
 java oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

command in command prompt, it was showing following lines

```
Error: Main method not found in class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, please define the main method as:
       public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: OracleDriver does not contain a main method. You cannot start a servlet without a corresponding container (like tomcat)... calling `java oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` does not make any sense.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have you copied classes12.jar in lib folder of your web application and set the classpath in eclipse.

Right-click project in Package explorer 
Build path -> Add external archives...

Select your ojdbc6.jar archive

Press OK

Or

Go through this [link](http://wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) and read and do carefully.

The library should be now referenced in the "Referenced Librairies" under the Package explorer. 
Now try to run your program again.

Comment: yes i copied classes12.jar ad ojdbc14.jar

Comment: which oracle version you are using either 8i or 10g

Comment: i am using oracle 11g R2

Comment: Then use ojdbc6.jar and delete classes12.jar and ojdbc14.jar and   Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"); and see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007174/what-jdbc-jar-to-use-with-oracle-11g-jdk-1-6-and-how-to-connect-to-the-db-itse

Comment: i changed jar files in lib folder to ojdbc6 and class.forName to oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver now also it was showing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Comment: empty the existing classpath and set this jar file in classpath

Comment: which ide you are using to compile this servlet. if you are compiling from cmd then give the what you have set in classpath and how you are compiling the servlet

Comment: Restart the server first and Download appropriate Oracle JDBC driver from here . If you are using Eclipse you need to add ojdbc6.jar which contains the OracleDriver class to your build path. It is usually located in: {ORACLE DRIVER INSTALL PATH}\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar

If you are not using an IDE you need to add the path to that JAR to your -classpath option.

Comment: Which jdk version you are using .then do these steps Right-click project in Package explorer
Build path
Add external archives...
Select your ojdbc6.jar archive
Press OK
The library should be now referenced in the "Referenced Librairies" under the Package explorer. Now try to run your program again.

Comment: I think i'm having latest jdbc driver. resently i installed it. i having jdk1.7.0_09

Comment: I didn't find Add external achives i'm newbie in eclipse.Please tell me in detail...

Comment: Go on project -> Right click on project - > Build Path - > Add External archives.

Comment: when i click on build path it was showing configure build path project -> Right click on project - > Build Path - >configure build path  What to do for this

Comment: Go through this link and read and do carefully http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Comment: Thank you sir That problem was resolved.You spent more time for me thank you very much. Now i got a new problem can you help for this The error was type Exception report

message java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
 skypark.Registration.doPost(Registration.java:67)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Answer (score 23):

Go through `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\lib`  path (this path may be differ based on where you installed the Tomcat server)  then past `ojdbc14.jar` if its not contain.

Then restart the server in eclipse then run your app on server

Comment: @Ravikumar D G: +1 also solved the problem for me.

Comment: Infact that is brilliant..my problem is solved

Answer (score 9):

team! 
For execute SQL-query from your Servlet you should add JDBC jar library in folder

```
WEB-INF/lib
```

After this you could call driver, example :

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

Now Y can use connection to DB-server

==> 73!

Comment: This worked for me. I am even referencing the ojdbc6.jar file from a different location in classpath, but this lib file must also have a copy of it. No need to restart.

Answer (score 4):

try to add ojdbc6.jar through the server lib "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\lib",

Then restart the server in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same kinda error but after copying the ojdbc14.jar into lib folder, no more exception.(copy ojdbc14.jar from somewhere and paste it into lib folder inside WebContent.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but was able to fix it by doing the following:

Right-click on the project -> Properties, then add the JAR (odjbc6 or 14) file in the deployment assembly.

Comment: Your answer refers to a specific IDE and setup but I think the OP's is different. They also seem to have added this jar to their classpath.