# HTTP Status 500 - null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jdbc, tomcat7

I wrote a java servlet program but when i run it, It was showing the Error HTTP Status 500 - null What it means ;
My source code is on [**this page**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904103/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-oracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver#comment19161338_13904103).

The error was

```
HTTP Status 500 - null
type Exception report
message null
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
skypark.Registration.doPost(Registration.java:56)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Please help me to resolve this....

Answer (score 2):

possibly

```
int phone=Integer.parseInt(phone1);
```

`phone1` is `null` passed

Answer (score 0):

hey correct ur html  there is no input type =number just correct as follows

```
Phone Number
</td><td>
<input type="text" name="phone">
</td></tr><tr><td>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error I can say that there is something other than a `number`passed to your function and this exception is raised.

Something like this:

```
int a = Integer.ParseInt(aStr);
```

where the `aStr` is `abc`

Answer (score 0):

You should have attribute name in the input tag.

```
<input type="text" name="xyz">
```

In d `servlet` access the value after parsing it, as follows.

```
int x=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("xyz"));
```