# wrong entryjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: oracle, jsp

The error occured:

wrong entryjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Someone please explain the error, what are the conditions of it appearing how can I resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change connection to Connection

Comment: Done, after that I got the above error. Will you please help me to resolve the abpove one as well.

Comment: Looks like you don't have this class on your build bath. Do you have a jar containing oracle driver added to your build path?

Comment: I have have a jar contained in the /WEB-INF directory nowhere else though What is a build path?

Comment: Read this post first [ClassNotFoundException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904103/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-oracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver). If it won't help ask again with more details of your project's structure and what you do when this error occurs.

Comment: Do I need to add buildpath even though I am using just jsp i.e. to say I am not using any IDE for java and stuuf. Just JSP.

Comment: So did you check if you deployed built project with this lib inside?