# Error -java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, database-connection

I want to connect to database in java web application.I wrote this code in servlet and i add related jar file(ojdbc) but when i run it,it gives me this error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

```
public class DBConnection extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DBConnection() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Connection con = null;  

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
              con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.101.84:1521:orcl","XXXX","XXXX");
              if(con!=null)
                 System. out.println("Connection Successful");
              else
                  System.  out.println("error");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println(e);
        }
...
```

what should i do?

Comment: Where did you put the JAR ? Put `classes12.jar` under `WEB-INF/lib` .

Comment: Do you have that jar in the class path ? Where do you put that jar ? Which application server you are using ?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007174/what-jdbc-jar-to-use-with-oracle-11g-jdk-1-6-and-how-to-connect-to-the-db-itse) for more.

Comment: I put my jar in Referenced library,I right-click  in my project-properties-java build path-add external...

Comment: You have to put the relevant jars in the server `WEB-INF/lib` folder too . It will be picked up from that location during runtime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having the same issue. What you need is to include the ojdbc6.jar file in the Deployment Assembly of the Project:

1. Right click on the project
2. select "Properties"
3. Select "Deployment Assembly" tab
4. Add your ojdbc6.jar file in it..

...and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by adding your jar of oracle driver into classpath environment variable just for testing purpose. or you can also load it at runtime by supplying the library into endorsed directory of your server (TOMCAT) otherwise you can copy your library file into common lib of your application server . It's just related to the oracle driver library which is not loading at startup of your application..

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem but got it fixed Right click on the project->properties and add your jar(ojdbc6 or 14) file in the deployment assembly then it will work...

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue and what you need is

You must include the ojdbc6.jar file in the Deployment Assembly of the Project.......

1)Right click on the project

2)select "Properties"

3)Select "Deployment Assembly" tab

4)Add your ojdbc6.jar file in it..

and the problem solve.